# When I use OAuth2 to query the number of followers,tell me not permitted to use OAuth2 on this endpoint

Tags: twitter, oauth-2.0

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gbcRg.png)
When I use OAuth2 to query the number of followers.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r7BCY.png)
When I use Oauth1.1, it tells me that I need more levels, it seems that this is not free
who can tell me the solution?